# What is the difference between "I learned everything" and "Everything I learned"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between the following terms?

> Everything I ate
>   I ate everything

or

> Everything I did
>   I did everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I ate everything.

That is a simple, complete sentence in English.  [subject-verb-object]

> everything I ate

That is not a sentence. It is a noun phrase.

It can be considered an abbreviation of "everything that I ate." For example:

"I liked everything I ate."

or

"Everything I ate was delicious."

---

All the other phrases can be explained in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

**Everything I know** refers to the knowledge you have.
**I know everything** implies that you possess all the knowledge in the world.